# Something similar to "stir up/kick hornets' nest"

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests, russian

stir up hornets' nest -- is an idiom similar to what I want. The difference is that I want something like with the meaning "break the order that's been around for a long time". Not necessarily cause a trouble. In russian it's "разворошить муравейник".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To send tremors through** , **send shockwaves through**, or **cause a seismic shift** are [metaphors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphor) that express the same intended meaning as the metaphor *to disturb an anthill* (your Russian phrase) or the metaphor *to disturb a hornet nest*, but more on a scale that humans can appreciate.

Both phrases ([and other earthquake related phrases](http://www.macmillandictionaryblog.com/a-tsunami-of-metaphors)) are used to describe a tremendous change or *shakeup* (mentioned in another answer) in the current order.

Answer (score 2):

create ***a paradigm shift***.  This term was first used in the philosophy of science.  [Wikipedia, paradigm shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradigm_shift) says:

> A paradigm shift, a concept identified by the American physicist and
>   philosopher Thomas Kuhn (1922–1996), is a fundamental change in the
>   basic concepts and experimental practices of a scientific discipline.
>   Kuhn contrasted these shifts, which characterize a scientific
>   revolution, to the activity of normal science, which he described as
>   scientific work done within a prevailing framework (or paradigm).

The term has since been used to announce a fundamental change in anything, and so has lost some of its power.  Some examples:

> From the [World Health
>   Organization](http://www.who.int/tdr/publications/documents/tdrnews-issue-82.pdf?ua=1),
>   Special Programme for Research & Training in Tropical Diseases (TDR)
>   sponsored by U N I C E F / U N D P / W o r l d B a n k / W H O: Making
>   a paradigm shift -- The Bamako 2008 Global Ministerial Forum on Research
>   for Health

This could be a legitimate use of the term, depending on how revolutionary the results from the Forum were.  The next example illustrates how pop psychology has co-opted the term:

> [Happiness in Four Essential Paradigm 
>   Shifts](http://gailbrenner.com/2009/08/paradigm-shifts/), by Dr. Gail 
>   Brenner ....    A paradigm shift is a revolution, a complete, radical
>   change in how   one views reality. With a paradigm shift, old
>   assumptions and beliefs   are seen to be false and no longer
>   applicable, and a completely new,   fresh way of being takes their
>   place. Do you want to be happy?   Consider the following, and prepare
>   for the inner revolution

Finally (although I could cite many more examples), there is a journal entitled [New Paradigm](http://www.newparadigmjournal.com/).  This journal announced a Shifting Paradigms Conference:

> The Shifting Paradigms Conference has the purpose of speaking for and
>   enhancing the change in values and attitudes of human beings through
>   an ongoing, open, informed, articulate debate and dialogue on key
>   issues affecting the future of humankind.

Comment: A 'revolution in thinking' is often used, eg 'We Need a Revolution in Thinking to Really Deal With Our Big Problems' {[HuffPost](http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/john-bird/social-reform-education_b_7555234.html)} 'Revolution' has been used metaphorically(?) for centuries, as in the 'Agricultural Revolution' and the 'Industrial Revolution', and obviously relates to gross change as well as change in ideology.

Answer (score 1):

TFD(idioms):

> **[shake up something](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/shake+up)** (also *shake something up*)
>   to cause big changes in a situation or organization
>
> The company announced that it
>   would shake up top management and cut 1,000 jobs.
>   Every new boss
>   likes to shake things up a bit when they take over.
>
> Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms Copyright © Cambridge
>   University Press 2003. Reproduced with permission.

Comment: And in general, *shake things up*.